# Fixing Movement Logic in Java

Tags: java, jframe, logic, chess

I currently developing a Chess Game in java using the eclipse IDE,

I Have all the movement of the pieces down apart from the Pawn which is the hardest because the **Pawn** has to be able to make to different moves

**The Pawn should be able to move twice at the start and then only one after that**

Currently I have set the pawn to only move twice but I am stuck on getting the rest of the logic to work

I have been working with the idea of an if/else statement

I could use some help writing it

*Here is the Code so far for the Pawn and I have included* *comment's for your use*

***Update to Problem it is only with the black pawn is not moving right I was able to set the white one the right way but not the black I dont know why it doesnt work***

```
 //Pawn Movement
    private boolean isValidPawnMove(int sourceRow, int sourceColumn, int targetRow, int targetColumn) {

        boolean isValid = false;
        if( isTargetLocationFree() ){
            if( sourceColumn == targetColumn){
                if(  sourcePiece.getColor() == Piece.COLOR_WHITE ){

                    // White Pawn
                    if( sourceRow+1 == targetRow || sourceRow == 1 && targetRow == 3){//Pawns can move to at the start then only 1 after that 
                        isValid = true;
                    }else{
                        isValid = false;
                    }
                }
                else{

                    // Black Pawn
                    if( sourceRow-1 == targetRow || sourceRow == -1 && targetRow == -3){
                        isValid = true;
                    }else{
                        isValid =  false;
                    }
                }
            }else{

                //If you try to move left or right into a different Column 
                isValid = false;

            }

        //Take square occupied by an opponent’s piece, which is diagonally in front 
        }else if( isTargetLocationCaptureable() ){

            if( sourceColumn+1 == targetColumn || sourceColumn-1 == targetColumn){
                //One column to the right or left
                if(  sourcePiece.getColor() == Piece.COLOR_WHITE ){
                    //White Piece 
                    if( sourceRow+1 == targetRow ){
                        //Move one up
                        isValid = true;
                    }else{
                        //Not moving one up
                        isValid = false;
                    }
                }else{
                    //Black Piece
                    if( sourceRow-1 == targetRow ){
                        //Move one down
                        isValid = true;
                    }else{
                        //Not moving one down
                        isValid = false;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                //Not one column to the left or right
                isValid = false;
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to explicitly check the source and target rows as white pawns can only move two forward from the second rank, so your logic becomes (for white):

```
if( sourceRow+1 == targetRow || sourceRow == 2 && targetRow == 4) {
```

Obviously you will also need to check that (sourceColumn, 3) is also empty.

Comment: I have added this but there was no change to the pawn movement, am I missing something ?

Comment: Does your row indexing start from 0 or 1? This code assumes 1. You might like to checkout how my chess engine does pawn move generation at https://github.com/BarrySW19/CalculonX/tree/master/src/main/java/nl/zoidberg/calculon/engine

Comment: Was able to get it fixed just had to adjust it to start from 0 not 1 thanks for the help, only problem is it is not applying to the black pawn ?

Answer (score 0):

In your class for the pawns, you can have an instance boolean, say,

```
boolean hasMoved
```

and initially make it false. If this boolean is false, then the pawn can move one OR two units. Whenever you move a pawn, you check this boolean, and if it's false, set it to true after moving it.  That should work out.

Comment: Would a counter be more practical?

Comment: No need. This is a one-time thing, and you'd have to use a boolean statement if using a counter(which you'd increment only once anyway) anyway. Also, considering booleans take up much less space than numbers, a boolean is definitely better.

Comment: I thought it would have to increment twice, but I don't play chess so what do I know - you answer is on the right track nonetheless ;)

Comment: I know I need the boolean to mark each pawn that was moved what i need is adding that to my current code can u help me with that ?

Comment: All you're showing us is code that tells whether the pawn is allowed to move... I assumed that you were using a class for the pieces, which you would easily enough be able to put a boolean in, but if not, what are you using to represent each piece?

Comment: yes and the code above also lets u set how the pawn moves as u can see from the code above the awn is currently set to 1 I need help writing the code to allow it to move twic at the start and then once after that all that should be done in this class above ?

Comment: Make a boolean that states whether the pawn is in its starting position. If so, then you can return true if the position is within 1 or 2 units of the piece. Otherwise, limit the allowance to 1 unit.

Comment: I have update my question with more infromation and the code for setting up the pieces hope u can help with the implention as i am still stcuk

Comment: Let me restate. Allow it to move 2 spaces if and only if its current row is the row at which it starts. That is what I tried to say in the last comment.

Or, if you make a setter method for your type field, you can easily split pawn into two types; moved and notmoved, and use that value to determine how much it can move.

Comment: But how ? the only code u have showed me is the boolean value

Answer (score 0):

In chess a pawn can choose if it wants to go one or two squares forward if it has never moved and therefore still stands on the second row. You have to ask, if it's on the second row and the two squares in front of it are empty and not only the "target location".

```
if( sourcePiece.getColor() == Piece.COLOR_WHITE ){

      // White Pawn
      if( sourceRow+1 == targetRow ){
          isValid = true;
      } else if (sourceRow+2 == targetRow && sourceRow == ROW_2) {
          if ((isFreeSquare(sourceColumn+1) && isFreeSquare(sourceColumn+2)) {
             isValid = true;
          } else {
              isValid = false;
          }
      } else {
          isValid = false;
      }
  }
  else{

      // Black Pawn
      ...
  }
```

You can leave the isFreeSquare(sourceColumn+2) code because you asked it with isTargetLocationFree() already. For black you have to ask if the pawn is still on ROW_7.

Comment: I have a question about the freesqure can u show me where i would add that method currently if i try to add it i get two errors, and also i am getting a problem with && sourceRow == ROW_2

Comment: If ROW_2 is not visible you can write Piece.ROW_2 or simply "1" without quotes. You have the isTargetLocationFree() method. Maybe you can expand it to return if a given square is free and deliver the coordinates as arguments.